# Perform segue to a view that may not have been created

Tags: ios, swift2

I have an app with 4 views, CheckAuthenticationView, HomeView, LoginView and DetailsView.

When the user starts the app the first view loaded is CheckAuthenticationView. This view checks the keychain for login information and if it exists, attempts to log the user in automatically and if successful, segues to DetailsView. If no information exists it performs a segue to the HomeView from which a user can then proceed to login.

Now on the DetailsView I have a button so the user can log out. If tapped, this clears any login information and performs an unwind (exit) segue to HomeView.

If a user does not logout but kills the app (restart phone etc), CheckAuthenticationView should produce a successful result meaning DetailsView will be loaded automatically. If this is the case, when I tap logout, the segue does not fire and the user remains on the DetailsView.

I am guessing that the segue does not happen because HomeView has not actually been created so there is nothing to segue to. Is there a way to segue to a view that has not yet been created?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by not yet created? If you haven't created the ViewController or any sort of view in your storyboard, then no you cannot segue to a view that does not exist.  If you have created it then you can just call:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
UIViewController *homeView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeView"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES(or NO) completion:nil];
```

Comment: Hi, I am calling in Swift, self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToHome", sender: self) if the user logs out. The problem I am facing is that if the user kills and restarts the app, HomeView is bypassed as the auto login script takes the user directly to the DetailsView.

Comment: As long as the target view **controller** is defined in the storyboard (and assigned a valid class), and the segue into it is named in the sotryboard,  `performSegueWithIdentifier()` should create the view controller then and there, right?

Comment: Not sure. The segue is named and the view controller is defined as if I perform the login manually (not through the Check view) then everything works as expected. If the DetailsView is loaded from the CheckAuthenticationView, after I tap the logout button, all the user defaults etc are removed, just no segue.

Comment: You could do something in the AppDelegate to check if your requirements are met and from there set the HomeView as the root view controller

Comment: @Tyler, I had been performing your suggested approach (self.presentViewController) however I found that doing this a number of times increased the memory allocation in the app. After 10 or so log out/in the app was increasing the memory each time.